# How do I use prepared statements for "select from xxx where xxx" using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have use a dict to store the condition, the number of keys and value in not fixed, such as

```
dict = {}
dict['v1'] = 'abc'
dict['v2'] = 123
...
dict['vn'] = xxx
```

My sql format is

> select * from tablename where v1 = 'abc' and v2 = 123 and ... vn = xxx

I have tried to turn the sql like this first:

> sql = "select * from tablename where v1 = %s and v2 = %s and ... vn = %s"

The format below can avoid sql injection, the question is that I dont know the number of values, how to write this  prepared statements. Thanks in advance.

> cursor.execute(sql, dict[v1], dict[v2], ..., dict[vn])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
sql = 'select * from tablename where ' + ' and '.join(k + ' = %s' for k in data)
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(data.values()))
```

Make sure you don't make any modifications to the dict between creating the `sql` string and executing the statement, since the ordering could change if you do.

Note that I renamed your dict to `data`, you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name because it will mask the built-in type.

I'm not completely sure if the conversion to a tuple is necessary.

Comment: watch out for the ordering in data.values() - it may look sorted but there are no guarantees

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps overkill, but you could use the excellent [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) library:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
engine = create_engine('mysql://your_connection_string')
meta = MetaData()
table = Table('table_name', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
s = select([table])
for key, val in dict.items():
   s = s.where(getattr(table.c, key)==val)
for row in conn.execute(s):
    print row
```

It may be worth it if you plan on doing a lot of SQL in your Python.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like following to paramerise the execute function:

```
def print_test(sql, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5):
    # just output some of the parameters..
    print param2, param3

print_test("whatever", *(i for i in range(5)))
```

Above is a simple example to illustrate what is happening in the print_test function. I am assuming that you would like some kind of sorting, therefore an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) would be a good fit for you. Then, you can simply export the values and the order will be consistent. Cast them as a tuple and the execute function will unroll what it needs.